# User registration fails with Firebase in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can you help me understand why this class does not refrain the user? In practice, when I enter email, password, etc. then I click on registration gives me that the user has not been registered, how can I do?

```java
    public void singUpUser(final String email , final String password, final String nickName, final String confermaPassword) {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        dialog.setMessage("Stiamo registrando l'utente....");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "crearUterWithEmail:Success");
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Map<String,Object> creaUtente = new HashMap<>();
                            creaUtente.put("email", email);
                            creaUtente.put("password", password);
                            creaUtente.put("nickName", nickName);
                            creaUtente.put("confermaPassword", confermaPassword);
                            mDatabase.child("Utente").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).updateChildren(creaUtente);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, activity_singIn.class);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "crearUterWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    }
```

Comment: If the task fails, the output of `Log.w(TAG, "crearUterWithEmail:failure", task.getException());` in your logcat should probably give you more information on why that is.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Bring me this: W/SingUpPresenter: crearUterWithEmail:failure
    com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

When you're getting the following error:

> There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

Most likely means that you're trying to use the credentials of a user that doesn't exist in Firebase authentication anymore. A possible reason would be, that you deleted it.

To solve this, you have to create the user again, using [createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and right after that try to sign in using [signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: yes but access does not give me an error the problem is in the registration ... in my project I have a special class that takes care of the login and one of the registration but the login one works perfectly the problem lies in the class indicated above

Comment: I don't see any class there that might create such a problem. But I'm 100% sure that you get that error because the user doesn't exist. So the only solution that I see, is to create the user again. Have you tried that?

Comment: i entered the singin function above

Comment: Please don't add information as an answer. Please edit the question. There is an edit button right under the question.

Comment: Besides that, I see that you're still digging l signing in, you're not recreating the user, right? So I'm order to have a successful authentication, the user should exist. If it doesn't, then it fails with that reception.

Comment: Hey Fabiola. Can I help you with other information?